# Can't upload more than 10 files

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm setting a form so i can upload multiple files:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="" id="MAX_FILE_SIZE">
    <input type="hidden" name="UPLOAD_IDENTIFIER" value="" id="progress_key">
    <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image-0">
</div>
```

This code will be cloned onClick, so I can choose more files.
The problem is, when I try to upload more than 10 files(e.g. 20 or 30 files), the script just dies and when I print $_Files, the array only has 10 items.

```
Array
(
    [image] => Array
        (
            [name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [1] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [2] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [3] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [4] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [5] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [6] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [7] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [8] => Nenufares.jpg
                    [9] => Nenufares.jpg
                )

            [type] => Array
                (
                    [0] => image/jpeg
                    [1] => image/jpeg
                    [2] => image/jpeg
                    [3] => image/jpeg
                    [4] => image/jpeg
                    [5] => image/jpeg
                    [6] => image/jpeg
                    [7] => image/jpeg
                    [8] => image/jpeg
                    [9] => image/jpeg
                )

            [tmp_name] => Array
                (
                    [0] => /tmp/phpAKZxze
                    [1] => /tmp/phplRShGv
                    [2] => /tmp/phpJz64SW
                    [3] => /tmp/phpBkfMoz
                    [4] => /tmp/phpraMZBl
                    [5] => /tmp/phpeqaEgk
                    [6] => /tmp/phpVwxvFv
                    [7] => /tmp/phplvYiUS
                    [8] => /tmp/phpPGhqGr
                    [9] => /tmp/php5kMZca
                )

            [error] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                    [1] => 0
                    [2] => 0
                    [3] => 0
                    [4] => 0
                    [5] => 0
                    [6] => 0
                    [7] => 0
                    [8] => 0
                    [9] => 0
                )

            [size] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 83794
                    [1] => 83794
                    [2] => 83794
                    [3] => 83794
                    [4] => 83794
                    [5] => 83794
                    [6] => 83794
                    [7] => 83794
                    [8] => 83794
                    [9] => 83794
                )

        )
```

I dont have any validator on zend side with count, or anything else, to block it..

Comment: Never send Max file size from client-side. Security hole.

Comment: Try :max_file_uploads (you need to do it in the php.ini)

Comment: default value is 20, you must be on shared hosting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your [php.ini configuration](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.max-file-uploads) :

```
; Maximum number of files that can be uploaded via a single request
max_file_uploads = 20
```

Comment: My hosting provider sys admin said that was not the problem, so I didn't care to check, but after all the answers I looked around and that was in fact the problem. After I requested the change, everything works perfect. Thanks all!

Comment: If you have doubts, you can use `ini_get('max_file_uploads')` to show what's in the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

max_file_uploads : The maximum number of files allowed to be uploaded simultaneously. Starting with PHP 5.3.4, upload fields left blank on submission do not count towards this limit.